# JAVA reflection cast object to class given by name of a specific supertype

Tags: java, generics, reflection

For example I've superclass Animal in a master package and sub-classes Dog and Cat in specific jars. All classes are JPA entities.

```
public class Animal {
}

public class Dog extends Animal{
}

public class Cat extends Animal{
}
```

I've a method that get Animal as parameter.

```
public createAnimal(Animal a){
   this.em.persist(a);
}
```

Now I want to pass an object of type Dog or Cat to that method

```
Animal a = ... //read from somewhere...
String myClass = "my.package.Dog";// at runtime
Class specific = Class.forName(myClass);
createAnimal(specific.cast(a));
```

I can't import Dog and Cat in my master package because it must be generic (I use it in other EARs).

So, how can I cast to specific classes defined by name and let the system know that is a subtype of Animal?

I need something like this:

```
Class<Animal> specific = Class.forName(myClass);
```

but I miss something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confused about what casting does. The cast syntax, which looks like: `(Dog) someAnimal;` does 3 completely unrelated things.

1) The first thing it does is type coercion, which actually converts a value from one kind to another. You get this ONLY IF the thing in the parens is primitive. Example: `int x = (int) 5.5;` will 'coerce' the 5.5 (which is a double) to be converted to 5 (an int).

2) The second thing it does is a type check. This is what happens where the thing in the parens is a non-primitive type, and not a type that is less specific than the expression. So, for example: `Animal a = someAnimal(); Dog d = (Dog) a;`. You seem to think that this operation converts an animal into a dog. It does not. All this does is typecheck: a is a variable of type `Animal`, and all that means is that it is either pointing at null, or pointing at some object that is either an instance of `Animal` (the class) itself *or any subtype thereof*. It is perfectly allright for 'a' to be of type Animal and be pointing at an object of type Cat (which is a subtype of Animal). Writing `(Dog) a` will typecheck: If a is currently pointing at either some instance of the class `Dog`, or null, this operation doesn't do anything at all. If it is NOT currently pointing at a dog (say, it is pointing at a cat), that expression will cause a `ClassCastException` to be thrown. **In no case will this operation ever convert anything**.

3. The final, most esoteric use is where you do something like: `Dog d = someDog(); Animal a = (Animal) d;`. In most cases this is a complete no-op and your IDE will warn you that doing this is completely meaningless; just `Animal a = d;` is just as legal. However, the type still changes which can have an effect on which method you are calling and what lambdas will be typed to. If this is gobbledygook to you, don't worry about it; this comes up basically never.

Further confusions you appear to hold:

The only valid assignment to a variable of `Class<Animal>`, is `Animal.class` (and null). `Dog.class` wouldn't be allowed there. If that was your intent, the correct type is `Class<? extends Animal>`.

You can cast *INSTANCES* reflectively using the `cast` method of any class. For example:

```
Dog dog = Dog.class.cast(someAnimal());
Dog dog = (Dog) someAnimal();
```

are entirely equivalent: This does nothing, unless someAnimal() returns a non-dog, in which case, that will cause a ClassCastException to be thrown.

If you want to check if some class instance is compatible with animal, you can do that:

```
Class<?> dogClass = Dog.class;
if (!Animal.class.isAssignableFrom(dogClass)) { /* error here */ }
```

Alternatively there's asSubclass:

```
Class<? extends Animal> animalClass = Dog.class;
Class<? extends Dog> dogClass = animalClass.asSubclass(Dog.class);
assert dogClass == animalClass;
```

Note how the asSubclass method again doesn't do anything, it just makes javac stop complaining. At runtime generics is eliminated; it's all just `Class`, the bit in the `<>` is gone. Hence, dogClass and animalClass are 2 variables both pointing to the exact same object (namely, the j.l.Class instance representing your Dog class).